# C# Querying an XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Good Day,

I am trying to query an XML document and have the following query:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"..\..\Data.xml");
var entries = root.Descendants()
              .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Entry")
              .ToList();

Console.WriteLine("There are {0} nodes...", entries.Count());
foreach (XElement v in entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.Value);
}
```

and this code works because it pulls the correct number of Entry nodes.  The Entry 
nodes look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Database xmlns="http://www.someurl.org/schemas">
    <InfoFromRecord>
        <BaseData>
            <Entry>
                <Date>2006-03-08</Date>XD
                <Time>09:20:00</Time>
                <EnteredBy>DNS</EnteredBy>
                <TextEntry>Record 1</TextEntry>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <Date>2006-03-08</Date>
                <Time>09:33:00</Time>
                <EnteredBy>MW</EnteredBy>
                <TextEntry>Record 2</TextEntry>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <Date>2006-03-08</Date>
                <Time>08:58:00</Time>
                <EnteredBy>BH</EnteredBy>
                <TextEntry>Record 3</TextEntry>
            </Entry>
        </BaseData>
    </InfoFromRecord>
</Database>
```

The problem is, I want to extract only the Date and Time, not all four fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's assume your entire XML file looks like this for a clear example:

```xml
<Entries>
    <Entry>
        <Date>2006-03-08</Date>
        <Time>09:33:00</Time>
        <EnteredBy>XX</EnteredBy>
        <TextEntry>Test Data</TextEntry>
    </Entry>
</Entries>
```

You could then do something like this:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\Data.xml");
var dateAndTimes =
    from d in document.Root.Descendants("Entry")
    select new
                {
                    Date = d.Element("Date").Value,
                    Time = d.Element("Time").Value
                };
```

From there, the `dateAndTimes` type will select an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) of the Date and Time. You can change the anonymous type to be your own type, or something else.

---

**EDIT**: The problem is your `xmlns`. Change your code like so:

```
XNamespace namespc = "http://www.someurl.org/schemas";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var dateAndTimes =
    from d in document.Root.Descendants(namespc + "Entry")
    select new
                {
                    Date = d.Element(namespc + "Date").Value,
                    Time = d.Element(namespc + "Time").Value
                };
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  It looks like there's nothing in document.Root.Descendants("Entry").  I thought Descendants will get any node in the document.

Comment: @coson Edited with update to answer. Namespaces weren't being taken into account.

Comment: That worked.  Turns out that default namespaces without prefixes needs to be accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (XElement v in entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.Element("Date").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(v.Element("Time").Value);
}
```

Do not forget that `Descendants` finds children at any level, i.e. children, grand-children, etc where `Elements` find only direct child. So i guess `Elements` is the safe option in most of the cases.

**EDIT : After seeing the XML**

You need to include the Namspace also when getting the data

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.someurl.org/schemas";
var entries = elm.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Entry").ToList();
foreach (XElement v in entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.Element(ns+"Date").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(v.Element(ns+"Time").Value);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried this and it doesn't work.  I'm getting a null reference exception

Comment: I put the entire document there now.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to try it but something like the following may give you what you are looking for

```
var entries = from i in root.Descendants() 
where Name=='entry' 
let date = i.Element('Date').Value 
let time = i.ELement('Time').Value 
select new Tuple<string,string>(date,time);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  IEnumerable<XElement> de = from el in xdoc.Descendants() select el;
  foreach (XElement el in de)
    {
     if (string.Equals(el.Name.ToString(), "movie", 
          `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`enter code here`             
               StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        date(el);
                    }
```

Comment: call the date function